# Dropdown toggling not working with ngTouch

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, angularjs-ng-touch

I need to stop event propagation on the main DIV and I set a flag on the original event object whether event occurred on the "more_vert" button. This works fine, but after to enable `ngTouch` the next code no work in OS: Android / Browser: Google Chrome.

```
<div ng-click="$event.originalEvent.dropdown || model.option()">
    <div>Name of item.</div>
    <span>Value of item.</span>
    <div class="dropdown" ng-click="$event.originalEvent.dropdown = true">
        <a id="menuActions" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" data-target="#" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button">
            <i class="material-icons md-24">more_vert</i>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="menuActions">
            <li>
                <a href="" class="ng-binding" ng-click="model.option1()">Option1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="" class="ng-binding" ng-click="model.option2()">Option2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="" class="ng-binding" ng-click="model.option3()">Option3</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I use Angular 1.4.7.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine. Actually work with ngTouch and Angular 1.5.5